# Best way to enqueue jQuery animations

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I need to make a sequence of animations in jQuery based in a timeline that is stored in a database. I'm storing this information with the name of function (animate, slide, fade...), the options/arguments of function and the callback of function.

I know jQuery does have the **[.queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)** method, but I really don't know how to take advantage of it (I think is more because I never used it).

**So, what is the difference between a jQuery animation queue and animate functions encapsulated in callbacks? Thinking about performance, what is the best way?**

Answer (score 2):

They queue automatically; just call them successively. For example, this:

```
$('#something').fadeOut().slideDown();
```

Will fade `#something` out, *then* slide it down.

Comment: So, the callback argument wouldn't serve for nothing?

Comment: No, not in that particular case. Note that only animations queue; other operations don't. So `$('#something').fadeOut().empty()` would empty the element before it finished fading out. That's what the callback is for, among other things.

Comment: And what is the best way to enqueue? With this way or with .queue?

Comment: If you're only queuing animations, then use this way, it's much easier.

Comment: Sorry if I will be rude, if I'm only queuing animations, why jQuery does have a function to enqueue animations?

Comment: It doesn't. The queues are how the animation queues are implemented in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand... What about the **[.queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)** method???

Comment: Yes, the `.queue` method is used to manipulate queues in a more complex manner than is possible by just running animation functions, but it's not something you need. I'm a little confused as to what it is you're confused about. Do you not understand because there are multiple ways to do the same thing?